# Getting Post Tags using Stack Exchange API

Tags: sql, api, stackexchange-api

Based on the query from Stack Exchange data explorer (SEDE):

```
select Tags.TagName, Count(Tags.TagName) as TagCount from Posts  
      join PostTags on Posts.Id = PostTags.PostID
      join Tags on PostTags.TagID = Tags.ID
      where Posts.Tags like '%<keras>%'
      group by Tags.TagName
      order by TagCount desc
```

There is a table named `PostTags`, which contains tags in a post.

By using Stack Exchange API, I can get the posts.
But how to get the tags in a post?

Comment: [I've created a SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1066656/stack-overflow-question-56626742) for the sake of reproducibility. It gets the number of the posts tagged with [keras] AND how many posts are tagged with [keras] and an another tag, e.g. [9980 posts are tagged with python and keras](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUvCT.png). Note SEDE is updated weekly. However, I find unclear what you are asking. Can you clarify what you mean by *I can get the posts*? You don't get any posts with this. And what do you mean with *how to get the tags in a post?* You should clarify

Comment: In SEDE query I can get the tags, but using the Stack exchange API how can I get it.

Comment: Oh, so you need to do what you did in SEDE, but in Stack Exchange API, right? Do you want the exact same behavior?

Comment: Yes, because in Stack exchange API I could not get PostTags. So is there any other way I can do the same thing in the API?

Comment: I think you should describe better what should be the desired output - what you want actually. E.g. you want to find all posts tagged with [keras] and how many are tagged [python], etc., right?

Comment: The query I mentioned what it does is, It will give the associated tags in Stackoverflow, ie., the tags and its count that occurred with the keras. I want to do the same using Stack exchange api. But there are no options as PostTags in Stack exchange api.

Answer (score 2):

The question is unclear.  But if you are trying to duplicate that SEDE query in [the Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), know that it's possible but not as simple.  The API was not set up for ad hoc data summaries.

In order to get a summary of the tags (also) present in [keras](/questions/tagged/keras) questions you must:

1. Beware of [paging](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging) and [quota limitations](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle).  There are currently [17699 questions tagged `keras`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=asc&sort=creation&tagged=keras&filter=!w-*Ytm8YGWVl9..xoC&site=stackoverflow&run=true). That's 177 API *pages*, or a substantial chunk of your daily API quota.
2. It is highly recommended that you register for and use [an API key](https://stackapps.com/questions/67/how-api-keys-work). This increases your quota from 300 to 10,000.
3. Fetch all questions that are tagged `keras`.
4. Loop through the results, totting up which tags are used, how often.
5. When the last page is fetched, do any final processing and display.

This fully functional demo illustrates the process <sup>(but limits to 2 pages of results to avoid exhausting quota on the demo)</sup>:

```js
var srchTag     = "keras";
const cYourKey  = ""; //  "&key=3TIJXXXXXXXXXXXXXZB0AA((";  // key is optional but very recommended
const cMaxPages = 2;  //  WARNING:  Only set this higher once you are sure the code is as you want it.
var tagStats    = {};

getPageOfQuestions (1);
function getPageOfQuestions (pageNum) {
    fetch (
        `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?tagged=${srchTag}&page=${pageNum}&pagesize=100&sort=creation&order=asc&site=stackoverflow&filter=!-W2eZY)NCj(NnIzhnVP6${cYourKey}`
    )
    .then (function (response) {
        if (response.ok)  return response.json();
        throw new Error (`API problem: Error ${response.status}, ${response.statusText}`);
    } )
    .then (function (rJsn) {
        if (rJsn.backoff  ||  rJsn.error_id) {
            throw new Error (`From API: Backoff ${rJsn.backoff}, Error: ${rJsn.error_id}, ${rJsn.error_message}, ${rJsn.error_name}`);
        }
        console.log (`Quota remaining: ${rJsn.quota_remaining}; Items found: ${rJsn.items.length}`);

        let allDone     = ! rJsn.has_more;
        let zQuestions  = rJsn.items;
        for (let qstn of zQuestions) {
            for (let zTag of qstn.tags) {
                let tagStat     = (tagStats[zTag] || 0) + 1;
                tagStats[zTag]  = tagStat;
            }
        }
        if (rJsn.has_more) {
            let newPageNm  = rJsn.page + 1;
            if (newPageNm <= cMaxPages)
                getPageOfQuestions (newPageNm);
            else
                allDone = true;
        }
        if (allDone) {
            //--- Do final processing here...
            console.log ("IMPORTANT:  Due to current limitations of Stack Overflow Snippets, only the 1st 40 lines are displayed."); // prod code won't need that limit.
            let J = 1;
            let tagsByPop = Object.keys (tagStats).sort ( (a, b) => (tagStats[b] - tagStats[a]) );
            for (let zTag of tagsByPop) {
                console.log ( (zTag + ":").padEnd(35),  tagStats[zTag]);   //  35 is max tagName length.
                if (J++ >= 40)  break;
            }
        }
    } );
};
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Given that getting a `backoff` when doing 177 consecutive requests is fairly common (depends on server load, which is often correlated to the time of day), it would be better to implement a delay for the `backoff`, rather than throw an error/reject. I've found it's also a good idea to add at least some explicit delay between the requests. The SE API has a maximum permitted request rate of 30 requests/s. While it's unusual to exceed that when waiting for the response of each request prior to sending the next one, it is possible. IME, a minimal delay also tends to result in fewer backoffs.

Comment: @Makyen, while you are correct in general, this is ***simplified Demo code***.  Furthermore, I never get a `backoff` when running just a few score requests with such code (unless quota is busted) -- and I've run ten's of thousands of naturally throttled requests. (More if you count public apps like [this one](http://output.jsbin.com/azeqec/12?sitename=stackoverflow).) ... ...  1) there is a natural delay between requests as they are sequential 2) I use "low cost" filters 3) Maybe I just have slower routes to the server (doubtful).

Comment: @Makyen, PS: When you run the snippet above what are the timestamps on the "Quota remaining" lines?  in my cases they are typically 0.3 seconds apart -- which works out to 3-4 requests per second -- well within the throttle limits.

Comment: I understood it's simplified Demo code. Given that it is demo code, it is, IMO, better to show handling `backoff` as a delay, rather than an error. In this instance, handling a `backoff` response is relatively trivial. Limiting requests to a maximum rate is good practice. I mentioned it because it can be naively done  with a single character beyond handling `backoff`. e.g. `getPageOfQuestions (newPageNm);` could be changed to `setTimeout(getPageOfQuestions, (rJsn.backoff * 1000 || 40), newPageNm);`, which would handle backoffs and limit requests to a maximum of 25/s (adds 7s to 177 requests).

Comment: Yes, if the responses are normal, then it's quite likely that the inherent round-trip and processing delays will result in a low enough rate such that it's not actually going to be a problem. However, in some cases, the delays may be *much* lower. As to getting a `backoff`, I've gotten them from single requests. My impression is that usually only happens near 0:00 UTC, but it's possible at other times too.